# Toggling Active and Inactive Images on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two separate images for each 'active' and 'inactive' link on my page. Each link toggles a different article on my web page.

```
<img src="/img/active.png" />
<img src="/img/inactive.png" />
```

I'm initially displaying all the inactive images on my page, but would like to display the `active` image respective to the link a user clicks.

**Note *** Each link, both active and inactive, will have a **unique** image url

```
<a href="#">
    <div>
        Click here for foo
        <img src="/img/inactive-123.png" />
    </div> 
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div>
        Click here for bar
        <img src="/img/inactive-345.png" />
    </div> 
</a>
```

There will potentially be 100+ links on my page, so I am looking for the most efficient & maintainable way to do this in jquery. I've thought about indexing these images with a number, but that could easily lead to incorrect associations between my articles - any ideas?

Comment: So basically, you want to change `inactive.png` to `active.png` and the other way on each click?

Comment: you could set a click listener on the `a`. then in the listener functiom do $(this).find("img") and set the src there

Comment: @MuFFes yes however each img has a unique URL, so I can't simply say toggle between 'active.png-' and 'inactive.png'. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this without jQuery pretty simply. I'm assuming that the structure of the elements inside the `<a>` will be the same as you wrote. But you can create a function that takes `this` (a element) and the `src` you want to replace the inner `img` tag with.  Of course you'll want to edit the function to be a bit more safe of about handling errors, e.g. index out of range exceptions.

```js
activateImg = function (elm, imgSrc) {
 elm.children[0].children[0].src = imgSrc;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="activateImg(this, 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=ACTIVE%20FOO&w=350&h=150')">
    <div>
        Click here for foo
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=INACTIVE%20FOO&w=350&h=150" />
    </div> 
</a>

<a href="#" onclick="activateImg(this, 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=ACTIVE%20BAR&w=350&h=150')">
    <div>
        Click here for bar
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=INACTIVE%20BAR&w=350&h=150" />
    </div> 
</a>
```

Edit:

If you want to swap the images back and forth just pass in both image links and swap depending on which one is the current `src`. http://plnkr.co/edit/LUDZEQF1AHXEZ7L83Fyb?p=preview

Edit2: I just re-read your comment and I think only one image can be active at a time. For that you could use an attribute to manage the state like `data-active`. I'll have an example soon.

Comment: This is pretty good, however it doesn't revert the previous image src to it's 'inactive' url

Comment: You can pass in both image links and just check which link is the current image and swap them. Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/LUDZEQF1AHXEZ7L83Fyb?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for clear JS, not JQuery as you mentioned

```
var tab = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
    tab[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (this.src.indexOf("inactive") !== -1){
                this.src = this.src.substring(0, this.src.length -12)
                this.src += "active.png"
            }
            else {
                this.src = this.src.substring(0, this.src.length -10)
                this.src += "inactive.png"
            }
    })
}
```

It will work as long as `inactive.png` or either `active.png` are on the end of the src value.

Answer (score 0):

If your links route to another page, something like the following should work:

```
$(function () {
  var pathname = window.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, "");
  $('a[href=' + pathname + '] img').attr('src', "/img/active.png");
});
```

Or do you need the image to change without refreshing the page?

Comment: Thanks Sam, it's all without refreshing the page sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple solution I'm happy with; I have created two `data` attributes on each image

```
<img 
    src=""
    data-inactive-src="/inactive-123.png"
    data-active-src="/active-123.png"
/>
<img 
    src=""
    data-inactive-src="/inactive-345.png"
    data-active-src="/active-345ng"
/>
```

Then when it comes time to swap the active for the inactive image, I do this

```
var currentIcon = $("#link-"+target).find('a div img') // don't worry about this line
var allIcons = $('a div img');

/** This section SHOULD keep track of the last 
    icon changed and change it back to inactive instead of looping through each element**/
allIcons.each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("inactive-src"));
});

/** Set the active icon image for the current target **/
currentIcon.attr("src", currentIcon.data("active-src"));
```

The `each()` loop will have to be swapped out, but this gives me perfect control of the active/inactive images. If you see any flaws with this please let me know!